# tf spits a lookup exception

Tags: ros, transforms, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using the tf package and specifically the tf.TransformerROS class in Python.
If I try calling its methods transformPose or transformPointCloud it returns a LookupException

```
tf.LookupException: Frame id /map does not exist! When trying to transform between /base_link and /map.
```

However if I try running the tf_monitor right after that I see that tf has knowledge of the frame

```
~>rosrun tf tf_monitor base_link map 
Waiting for transform chain to become available between /base_link and /map 

RESULTS: for /base_link to /map 
Chain is: /base_link -> /base_footprint -> /odom_combined -> /map 
Net delay     avg = 0.00684423: max = 0.054 

Frames: 
Frame: /base_footprint published by /robot_pose_ekf Average Delay: 0.0185 Max Delay: 0.026 
Frame: /base_link published by /robot_state_publisher Average Delay: 0.0075 Max Delay: 0.008 
Frame: /odom_combined published by /slam_gmapping Average Delay: 0 Max Delay: 0 

All Broadcasters: 
Node: /robot_pose_ekf 33.5196 Hz, Average Delay: 0.0185 Max Delay: 0.026 
Node: /robot_state_publisher 55.5556 Hz, Average Delay: 0.0075 Max Delay: 0.008 
Node: /slam_gmapping 25 Hz, Average Delay: 0 Max Delay: 0
```

I'm running gazebo simulation and have ROBOT=sim set.
Any ideas how to get transformPointCloud to work?

Edit:
Here is (simplified) the part of the code that deals with tf

```
import roslib
roslib.load_manifest(PKG)
import rospy
import tf

class Class():
    def __init__(self):
        #...
        self.tfTrasformer = tf.TransformerROS()
        #...
        
        
    # somewhere in the methods
    obj.object.cluster = self.tfTrasformer.transformPointCloud("/map",obj.object.cluster)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9939/tf-spits-a-lookup-exception/) by [Dimitar Simeonov](https://answers.ros.org/users/256/dimitar-simeonov/) on ROS Answers with karma: 535 on 2011-05-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-05-11**:
Could you post/link to your code that makes the TransformerROS instance as well as the code that calls the methods that are failing? If possible a minimal example that reproduces the problem would be best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should use the TransformListener class, not TransformerROS. I'm pretty sure that TransformerROS does not automatically subscribe to the "/tf" topic, which would be why you are getting errors about missing frames.

For example usage, see the [Python TF tutorials](http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf%20listener%20%28Python%29).

I'm not really sure why there are no docs for the TransformListener class [online](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/tf/html/python/tf_python.html#transformlistener), since there are doc strings in the source code.

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2011-05-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-05-11**:
Ya... not sure what's up with the docs... You may want to file a ticket against tf for the docs describing what you were unable to find/the source of your confusion... at the least, there are doc strings for e.g. TransformListener in the source that might help if they were in the generated API pages

**Comment by [Dimitar Simeonov](https://answers.ros.org/users/256/dimitar-simeonov/) on 2011-05-11**:
Ha, I had no idea it subclasses it - at least this isn't really visible from the documentation or the tutorials. Thanks, I'll try it tomorrow and see how it works.

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-05-11**:
No need. The TransformListener inherits from TransformerROS, so has all of the same methods. The only important difference in this case is that the TransformListener automatically subscribes to "/tf" whereas TransfomerROS needs somebody to shove transform info into it.

**Comment by [Dimitar Simeonov](https://answers.ros.org/users/256/dimitar-simeonov/) on 2011-05-11**:
Thank you. But I looked at these links before I posted my question and I'm not sure: should I write my own function which applies translation and rotation to coordinates? I am happy to do so but thought something like that existed in ROS already.